# Accessing webserver

Tags: html, sql-server

I have a vague question and I'm not excactly a computer specialist, so don't be too hard on me.

I have a program running on a linux server, which is assembled in a html document, which I run on the linux server using firefox. Basically it's a number of png pictures, which I can interact with. I can click on them, and data about this particular picture appear. This data stems from a mysql database.

Everything is working fine on the linux server.

Now I'm trying to acces this program through another computer coupled up on our local network, by pressing the url of the linux server into a webbrowser. This also works. I see excactly the same png files, except when I click on them, nothing happens. It seems there is no connection to the mysql server, where the data is on.

I know it's vague, but does anyone have a clue about what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Firstly, thanks for being polite in the way you ask. However, there is not much chance of getting an answer to such a vague question. Don't take it the wrong way if you are down voted or the question is closed, it's simply because users don't feel the question is answerable in it's current format or it's not useful to future visitors. Ideally, you want a small problem that you have identified that other users can recreate, with errors that provide useful insight to the problem. This, unfortunately, you have not provided and also, the [sql-server] tag doesn't really match what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

First step see the permissions on the server side!
Second step see how you are doing the connections!
For more help you have to explain how you are doing these two steps.
I had a similar problem with a file upload and it was due to errors performing these two steps.